# Is there a way to dynamically resize gecko browser in winforms c# with certain specifications?

Tags: c#, winforms, browser

I'm making a browser based on the Mozilla Gecko engine in visual c#, but I want to leave space at the top for the url bar and tabs. How can I dynamically change the size with the window while keeping a 60 pixel space above the browser no matter the size?

I've already tried checking in `Form1()` by just setting a variable to the forms height minus 60, but it only seems to check when the code starts running and doesn't check again.

```
int browserHeight = this.Height - 60;
int browserWidth = this.Width;

geckoWebBrowser1.Height = browserHeight;
geckoWebBrowser1.Width = browserWidth;
```

I expect my variables `browserHeight` and `browserWidth` to automatically update when the forms dimensions change, and I expect my `geckoWebBrowser1`'s dimensions to change when my variables have changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming `WinForms` here.

Use the `Anchor` property of your control (`geckoWebBrowser`).  In the designer, look at the properties and look for `Anchor`.  Set that to `Top`, `Left`, `Bottom` and `Right" (i.e. all of the options).

Now, manually align your browser how you want (i.e. with your 60px space).

That's it! Now it will auto-size with your form.

Comment: Thanks, I never even thought of using the designer, I was overcomplicating it a bit with code!